# Make changes not tied to a state in design mode in flash builder 4

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, state, designmode

If I have a component that has some states defined, is there a way to make changes in design mode but not have it tied to a particular state?  For example, if I have state1 and state2, any changes in design mode will be based on state1 or state2 (i.e. width.state1).  I understand this is the direction Flex is going in but I'm transitioning from a Flex 3 app and right now I just want to make the change to width and not width.state1.

Comment: Don't use design mode and code it yourself?

Comment: It is much easier to experiment with layouts in design mode and shift things around by pixel by pixel.  Right now, I'm making the changes in design mode and having to adjust the code afterwards which is a real waste of time

Comment: If you want to do that, that's what catalyst is for.  Design mode simply *should* not be used by any developer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the "features" of Flash Builder that I'm not a fan of. It wouldn't be so bad if you could select `<base state>` from the State drop down list but for whatever reason, that's not an option.

As far as I know, there's no way to use design mode without affecting a specific state. I would go with J_A_X's suggestion and just code it yourself in Source mode.

**EDIT**: Flextras added a good example of how to code properties for a specific state or for all states as well.

Comment: Yea, that's what I'm using right now. I have width="100" already and then I change the width in design mode but it makes the change to width.state1. So if I change width to 110 in design mode, the mxml code is width="100" and width.state1="110". That leaves width in state2 as 100 even though I wanted to make the design mode change to 110 for all states and I have to go in and adjust the code in mxml.

Comment: @Steven I've had that happen to me several times as well. Now I typically never use Flash Builder's design mode. I just code everything by hand. It makes your code cleaner too. For example, if you select a label in design mode and make it bold it adds the `fontWeight="bold"` property. If you remove the bold, it changes the property to `fontWeight="normal"`, which is the default anyhow. It can just lead to unnecessary and unwanted code.

Comment: What I do if I want to use design mode for a component with multiple states but want to make the changes to all states is to just comment out the states mxml and then go into design mode and putting it back in when done

Comment: @Steven You could try that, sure. I haven't tried that approach personally, but I believe it could work.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how to do it in design mode, but in MXML you have something like this:

```
<component id="myid" width.state1="100" width.state2="100" />
```

If you want to just set a width that is not tied to a state, do this:

```
<component id="myid" width="100"  />
```

Also, I'm unsure if I'd make any blanket statements on the direction Flex is going.  To date Adobe has changed directions a few times.  When building Mobile Skins; they recommend against using MXML completely; and for performance states in mobile skins are hard-coded changes in the code.

Answer (score 1):

There is one way to force the properties to be independent of the view state : right mouse click in the design window with the relevant component selected, and choose the last option in the context menu 'Apply Current Properties to All States'. The option is not really flexible though : it will remove all view dependent properties that you ever set for that component. And be careful also with which component you have selected. Right clicking in the design window will select a different component if you're not in the right place with your mouse pointer.